# Audio Queues for multi channel real time audio processing on Mac

Tags: macos, real-time, audio-recording, audioqueueservices

I have a 4 mic array connected to an iMac via an external audio interface (RME Fireface). I need to record from all 4 simultaneously, get individual signals, perform some operations, and play an output sound, all in real time.

First of all, the audio inputs in Mac system preferences does not show 4 separate devices but just one RME FireFace. How then, can i find the port addresses for each mic?

Secondly, the main question - Can i use Audio Queues for this purpose? The [Audio queues documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343) has no clear information on multi channel audio input and signal processing.

Comment: You will probably just be capturing one stream of 4 channel audio - the samples for each of the 4 mics will be interleaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audio Queues does not support input from 4 channels simultaneously, based on [this thread].(http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/coreaudio-api@lists.apple.com/2011-01/msg00174.html).

You probably have to go with [CoreAudio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html), which is a lower level API but claims "scalable multichannel input and output" which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. This was giving me a lot of trouble but i still am not able to figure  out how to actually set the device to record from. The examples (like CAplaythru) are not very clear.

Comment: If you have a question about the API's you can create a new question :-)